Implementing functions in module types
I have the following module type:
module type Element = sig
  type t
  type mystruct = {x: int; y: int}
  val (<) : t -> t -> bool
  val string_of_element : t -> string
  (* val (>) : t -> t -> bool = not (<) *)
end

Where as you can see, I want the type t to be generic but I want mystruct to have a specific structure. The problem is that when I create a module MyInteger that "implements" module Element as follow:
module MyInteger = struct
  type t = int
  let (<) a b = a < b
  let string_of_element = string_of_int
end

It complains that

The type `mystruct' is required but not provided

And it does not work unless I redefine type mystruct in this module.
I don't understand why it just don't use the type I defined in the module type? Is there a way I can make it do that?
Same thing with function (>), how can I make OCaml consider (>) the opposite of (<) whatever it is?

I suspect there is some element of the XY problem at work here.

You were on the right track by tagging "functor." When the definition of some other function is dependent on another, functors are a good fit.
In the following I only define the less than predicate, but the functor uses that to generate greater than and equal predicates.
# module type COMPARABLE = sig
    type t
    val lt : t -> t -> bool
  end;;
module type COMPARABLE = sig type t val lt : t -> t -> bool end
# module Compare (M : COMPARABLE) = struct
    type t = M.t
    let lt = M.lt
    let gt a b = lt b a
    let eq a b = not (lt a b) && not (gt a b)
  end;;
module Compare :
  functor (M : COMPARABLE) ->
    sig
      type t = M.t
      val lt : t -> t -> bool
      val gt : t -> t -> bool
      val eq : t -> t -> bool
    end
# module A = Compare (struct type t = int let lt a b = a < b end);;
module A :
  sig
    type t = int
    val lt : t -> t -> bool
    val gt : t -> t -> bool
    val eq : t -> t -> bool
  end
# A.(lt 4 5, gt 4 5, eq 4 5);;
- : bool * bool * bool = (true, false, false)

Now, because the first part of the definition of the Compare functor is just aliasing the contents of the COMPARABLE module passed to it as M, we can use include instead.
# module Compare (M : COMPARABLE) = struct
    include M
    let gt a b = lt b a
    let eq a b = not (lt a b) && not (gt a b)
  end;;
module Compare :
  functor (M : COMPARABLE) ->
    sig
      type t = M.t
      val lt : t -> t -> bool
      val gt : t -> t -> bool
      val eq : t -> t -> bool
    end

We could carry this further to define ge and le functions as well. All based on the less than predicate being defined.
# module Compare (M : COMPARABLE) = struct
    include M
    let gt a b = lt b a
    let eq a b = not (lt a b) && not (gt a b)
    let le a b = lt a b || eq a b
    let ge a b = gt a b || eq a b
  end;;
module Compare :
  functor (M : COMPARABLE) ->
    sig
      type t = M.t
      val lt : t -> t -> bool
      val gt : t -> t -> bool
      val eq : t -> t -> bool
      val le : t -> t -> bool
      val ge : t -> t -> bool
    end


Modules types are specifications. They do not implement anything, neither function nor types.
When you write the module type
module type Element = sig
  ...
  type mystruct = {x: int; y: int}
  ...
end

you are specifying that every implementation must define its own variant of mystruct, which is indeed not very useful.
The solution is most probably to move the shared type definition outside of the module type specification:
type mystruct = {x:int; y:int}
module type Element = sig ... end

If the mystruct type has some dependency on other types in the Element module type specification, a good solution is to make the shared type definition polymorph over the implementation-dependent part:
type 'a mystruct = { x:'a; y:int }
module type Element = struct
  ...
  type t
  type mystruct_elt = t mystruct
  ...
end

Similarly, you can use a higher-order function to define derived functions
let make_gt (<) x y = y < x
module I = struct
  let (<) = ...
  let (>) = make_gt (<)
end

If there are more than a handful of derived functions, you can use a functor to extend the base module implementation:
module Extend(X:Base_element) = struct
  let (>) x y = X.( y < x )
  ...
end
module Full = struct
  module Core = struct ... end
  include Core
  include Extend(Core)
end

